# compile error with hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

I am trying to install hadoop 2.3.0 on windows7

using windows sdk 7.1

maven command: 
`mvn package -Pdist,native-win -DskipTests -Dtar`

I receive below error:

I searched for this error but I couldn't find any solution

```
[ERROR] location: class ApplicationImpl
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\application\ApplicationImpl.java:[391,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ApplicationContainerFinishedEvent
[ERROR] location: class AppFinishTransition
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\application\ApplicationImpl.java:[392,11] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ApplicationContainerFinishedEvent
[ERROR] location: class AppFinishTransition
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\application\ApplicationImpl.java:[416,14] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class LogHandlerAppFinishedEvent
[ERROR] location: class AppCompletelyDoneTransition
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\localizer\LocalizedResource.java:[224,14] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class LocalizerResourceRequestEvent
[ERROR] location: class FetchResourceTransition
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\localizer\LocalizedResource.java:[254,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ResourceFailedLocalizationEvent
[ERROR] location: class FetchFailedTransition
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\localizer\LocalizedResource.java:[255,11] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ResourceFailedLocalizationEvent
[ERROR] location: class FetchFailedTransition
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\localizer\security\LocalizerTokenSelector.java:[45,34] error: package
 LocalizerTokenIdentifier does not exist
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\localizer\security\LocalizerTokenSelector.java:[46,22] error: cannot
find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class LocalizerTokenIdentifier
[ERROR] location: class LocalizerTokenSelector
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\localizer\ResourceLocalizationService.java:[275,26] error: cannot fin
d symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class LocalizerTokenSecretManager
[ERROR] location: class ResourceLocalizationService
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\localizer\ResourceLocalizationService.java:[308,12] error: cannot fin
d symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ApplicationLocalizationEvent
[ERROR] location: class ResourceLocalizationService
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\localizer\ResourceLocalizationService.java:[311,36] error: cannot fin
d symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ContainerLocalizationRequestEvent
[ERROR] location: class ResourceLocalizationService
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\localizer\ResourceLocalizationService.java:[317,39] error: cannot fin
d symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ContainerLocalizationCleanupEvent
[ERROR] location: class ResourceLocalizationService
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\localizer\ResourceLocalizationService.java:[321,12] error: cannot fin
d symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ApplicationLocalizationEvent
[ERROR] location: class ResourceLocalizationService
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\localizer\ResourceLocalizationService.java:[579,8] error: cannot find
 symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class LocalizerResourceRequestEvent
[ERROR] location: class ResourceLocalizationService.LocalizerTracker
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\localizer\ResourceLocalizationService.java:[580,11] error: cannot fin
d symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class LocalizerResourceRequestEvent
[ERROR] location: class ResourceLocalizationService.LocalizerTracker
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\localizer\ResourceLocalizationService.java:[581,33] error: strings in
 switch are not supported in -source 1.6
[ERROR] (use -source 7 or higher to enable strings in switch)
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\localizer\ResourceLocalizationService.java:[582,13] error: cannot fin
d symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable PUBLIC
[ERROR] location: class ResourceLocalizationService.LocalizerTracker
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\localizer\ResourceLocalizationService.java:[585,13] error: cannot fin
d symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable PRIVATE
[ERROR] location: class ResourceLocalizationService.LocalizerTracker
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\localizer\ResourceLocalizationService.java:[586,13] error: cannot fin
d symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable APPLICATION
[ERROR] location: class ResourceLocalizationService.LocalizerTracker
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\localizer\ResourceLocalizationService.java:[642,36] error: cannot fin
d symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class LocalizerResourceRequestEvent
[ERROR] location: class ResourceLocalizationService.PublicLocalizer
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\localizer\ResourceLocalizationService.java:[703,12] error: cannot fin
d symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class LocalizerResourceRequestEvent
[ERROR] location: class ResourceLocalizationService.PublicLocalizer
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\localizer\ResourceLocalizationService.java:[719,36] error: cannot fin
d symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ResourceFailedLocalizationEvent
[ERROR] location: class ResourceLocalizationService.PublicLocalizer
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\localizer\ResourceLocalizationService.java:[762,44] error: cannot fin
d symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class LocalizerResourceRequestEvent
[ERROR] location: class ResourceLocalizationService.LocalizerRunner
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\localizer\ResourceLocalizationService.java:[764,44] error: cannot fin
d symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class LocalizerResourceRequestEvent
[ERROR] location: class ResourceLocalizationService.LocalizerRunner
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\localizer\ResourceLocalizationService.java:[778,22] error: cannot fin
d symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class LocalizerResourceRequestEvent
[ERROR] location: class ResourceLocalizationService.LocalizerRunner
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\localizer\ResourceLocalizationService.java:[780,9] error: cannot find
 symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class LocalizerResourceRequestEvent
[ERROR] location: class ResourceLocalizationService.LocalizerRunner
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\localizer\ResourceLocalizationService.java:[868,8] error: cannot find
 symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class LocalizerResourceRequestEvent
[ERROR] location: class ResourceLocalizationService.LocalizerRunner
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\localizer\ResourceLocalizationService.java:[918,26] error: cannot fin
d symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ResourceFailedLocalizationEvent
[ERROR] location: class ResourceLocalizationService.LocalizerRunner
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\localizer\ResourceLocalizationService.java:[931,26] error: cannot fin
d symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ResourceFailedLocalizationEvent
[ERROR] location: class ResourceLocalizationService.LocalizerRunner
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\localizer\ResourceLocalizationService.java:[1000,13] error: cannot fi
nd symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class LocalizerResourceRequestEvent
[ERROR] location: class ResourceLocalizationService.LocalizerRunner
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\localizer\ResourceLocalizationService.java:[1025,10] error: cannot fi
nd symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class LocalizerTokenIdentifier
[ERROR] location: class ResourceLocalizationService.LocalizerRunner
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\localizer\ResourceLocalizationService.java:[1026,16] error: cannot fi
nd symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class LocalizerTokenIdentifier
[ERROR] location: class ResourceLocalizationService.LocalizerRunner
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\localizer\ResourceLocalizationService.java:[1027,24] error: cannot fi
nd symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class LocalizerTokenIdentifier
[ERROR] location: class ResourceLocalizationService.LocalizerRunner
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\localizer\ContainerLocalizer.java:[149,39] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable LocalizerTokenIdentifier
[ERROR] location: class ContainerLocalizer
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\api\im
pl\pb\service\LocalizationProtocolPBServiceImpl.java:[49,15] error: cannot find
symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class LocalizerHeartbeatResponsePBImpl
[ERROR] location: class LocalizationProtocolPBServiceImpl
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\logaggregation\LogAggregationService.java:[411,8] error: cannot find
symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class LogHandlerAppStartedEvent
[ERROR] location: class LogAggregationService
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\logaggregation\LogAggregationService.java:[412,13] error: cannot find
 symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class LogHandlerAppStartedEvent
[ERROR] location: class LogAggregationService
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\logaggregation\LogAggregationService.java:[419,8] error: cannot find
symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class LogHandlerContainerFinishedEvent
[ERROR] location: class LogAggregationService
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\logaggregation\LogAggregationService.java:[420,13] error: cannot find
 symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class LogHandlerContainerFinishedEvent
[ERROR] location: class LogAggregationService
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\logaggregation\LogAggregationService.java:[425,8] error: cannot find
symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class LogHandlerAppFinishedEvent
[ERROR] location: class LogAggregationService
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\logaggregation\LogAggregationService.java:[426,13] error: cannot find
 symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class LogHandlerAppFinishedEvent
[ERROR] location: class LogAggregationService
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\api\im
pl\pb\client\LocalizationProtocolPBClientImpl.java:[62,17] error: cannot find sy
mbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class LocalizerHeartbeatResponsePBImpl
[ERROR] location: class LocalizationProtocolPBClientImpl
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\loghandler\NonAggregatingLogHandler.java:[104,8] error: cannot find s
ymbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class LogHandlerAppStartedEvent
[ERROR] location: class NonAggregatingLogHandler
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\loghandler\NonAggregatingLogHandler.java:[105,13] error: cannot find
symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class LogHandlerAppStartedEvent
[ERROR] location: class NonAggregatingLogHandler
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\loghandler\NonAggregatingLogHandler.java:[116,8] error: cannot find s
ymbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class LogHandlerAppFinishedEvent
[ERROR] location: class NonAggregatingLogHandler
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\loghandler\NonAggregatingLogHandler.java:[117,13] error: cannot find
symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class LogHandlerAppFinishedEvent
[ERROR] location: class NonAggregatingLogHandler
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\container\ContainerImpl.java:[446,28] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ApplicationContainerFinishedEvent
[ERROR] location: class ContainerImpl
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\container\ContainerImpl.java:[450,28] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class LogHandlerContainerFinishedEvent
[ERROR] location: class ContainerImpl
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\container\ContainerImpl.java:[469,12] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ContainerLocalizationCleanupEvent
[ERROR] location: class ContainerImpl
[ERROR] C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-s
erver-nodemanager\src\main\java\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\nodemanager\contai
nermanager\container\ContainerImpl.java:[574,18] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureExc
eption
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command

[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager
```

Is it something related to pom?

I suspected it has something to do with packages version, so I tried to edit `C:\hdfs\hadoop-yarn-project\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager\pom.xml`, but with no luck!

Comment: Some dependencies missing in the pom.xml. You need add those dependencies. Or you have to build something else before so that if would create those dependencies.

Comment: @Jay I tried to `mvn dependency:resolve` or `mvn dependency:tree` to resolve dependencies, but the error remains

Comment: Please let know where you downloaded the source, and the steps you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem when using winrar to extract the hadoop jar. Files of which the path is too long will not be extracted, that's why when you compile the source, you find yourself missing some files.

Try to move the jar to the directory such as D:\ or E:\ then extract it. The problem will disappear.

Also try http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/38/build-install-configure-run-apache-hadoop-2.2.0-microsoft-windows-os.

Good Luck.