# Hadoop 2.6.0 Maven Compilation Error on hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

I am running into a particular error I haven't seen around on the internet
when compiling hadoop from source.

It seems to be a problem with some missing java packages the error occurs
when trying to compile `hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager`

Looks like some java packages are missing or were not gotten by maven.
The build log of everything after the error ocurred is on this gist: https://gist.github.com/grplyler/46025ba50664260fee75

Here is the command I used to compile and package hadoop on the
root of its source:

`mvn package -Pdist,native -DskipTest -Dtar -X`

My system and environment details:

```
OS: Linux Mint 17 (Ubuntu 14.10)
Java: java version "1.7.0_75"
Protobuf: 2.5.0
Maven: 3.0.5
Hadoop: 2.6.0
```

Also installed so I can build the native code (because i want the fuse-dfs part) are:

```
cmake
zlib 
zlib1g-dev 
libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

A similar problem is detailed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22781275/compile-error-with-hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager) But it was cause by windows maximum path lengths which is not my case here.

I have been working on this for 2 days now, any feedback or advice as to a solution to the problem would be much appreciated.

```
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:729)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.TestCompilerMojo.execute(TestCompilerMojo.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try and update to the newest version of maven(which is no longer picked up by apt-get)

```
sudo apt-get remove maven
sudo apt-get install gdebi

wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/natecarlson/maven3/ubuntu/pool/main/m/maven3/maven3_3.2.1-0~ppa1_all.deb

sudo gdebi maven3_3.2.1-0~ppa1_all.deb

sudo ln -s /usr/share/maven3/bin/mvn /usr/bin/maven
```

Comment: Thanks i'll try that. BTW What is `gdebi`? Why not `dpkg -i maven3_3.2.1-0~ppa1_all.deb`

Comment: From google - gdebi is a simple tool to install deb files. apt does the same, but only for remote (http, ftp) located package repositories. It has a graphical user interface but can also be used in your terminal.

Comment: Still the same problem after installing the newer maven. This seems to be the most occuring error:
`[ERROR] symbol:   method resource()
[ERROR] location: class TestNMWebServices
[ERROR] /usr/local/src/hadoop-2.6.0-src/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server/ha
doop-yarn-server-nodemanager/src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/server/nodemanager/webapp/T
estNMWebServices.java:[277,20] error: cannot find symbol`